# mediaelement.js Video Height not calculated correctly

Tags: mediaelement.js

I updated a project from mediaelement.js 2.23.4 to 4.2.9.
I've read the [migrate instructions](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement#migration) and I think haven't missed anything.
After the update videos are not displayed correctly because the height is not calculated correctly.

In setResponsiveMode t.media.videoWidth/Height are always 0 and 
I noticed that "loadedmetadata" is not fired.

On the previous version,loadedmetadata is fired and then eventually setResponsiveMode and at that time t.media.videoWidth/Height is set.

My code looks like this:

```
$("video").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("preload", "metadata");
                var src = this.src;
                $(this).mediaelementplayer({
                    features          : ["playpause", "progress", "tracks"],
                    defaultVideoWidth : 480,
                    defaultVideoHeight: 270,
                    type              : 'video/flv',
                    renderers: ['html5', 'flash_video'],
                    pluginPath: 'js/',
                    classPrefix:'mejs-',
                    shimScriptAccess: 'sameDomain',
                    success           : function (e) {

                    }
                });
            });
```

I don't have a minimal example at the moment but I suspect it will work on a clean project.
My project is complicated and I think I missed something.
Any ideas?

PS,the only problem is the height,the video is rendered.played without problems (e.g if I edit the height of the element using developer tools)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for MediaElementJsPlayer](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/api.md#mediaelementplayer) says that defaultVideoHeight is used if no height attribute has been specified in the video tag. Does your video tag contain height attribute?.

You can set the video height for each video using videoHeight configuration option. Also check out the stretching option. Its default value is auto. You may want to set it to none so the player does not auto resize.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nadir. No,I don't have the video height. I've read the documentation and I've seen the actual source code. On 2.34.3 ,after I initialize the element ( $(this).mediaelementplayer)  the "loadedmetadata" event is fired and the height is set to the correct value. I know that loadedmetadata isn't 100% reliable but there doesn't seem to be an issue on 2.34.4

Comment: You can try to set the player height using the setPlayerSize function. It allows setting the width and height of the player. The function can be called inside the page load event handler